# I wanted to check allure testng report Even the example project fails

Tags: testng, maven-plugin, allure

I did search for the exception online which recommended to change versions and I changed the versions still no result.

I went to the allure Git (https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example)

Followed these steps
To generate Allure Report you should perform following steps:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:allure-examples/allure-testng-example.git
$ mvn clean test
$ mvn site
```

Result and the exception is found below

```
maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ allure-testng-example ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.2
Jun 01, 2017 4:41:30 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
WARNING: Error injecting: ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
while locating ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportMojo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
>   while locating ru.yandex.qatools.allure.report.AllureReportMojo

Allure Maven Plugin requires Maven version 3.1.1 or higher.

In case you need to generate report even if your tests are failed you need to specify `testFailureIgnore` property to Maven Surefire (already present in specified example).

Comment: Changing the version of maven it worked.but now .
allure-testng-example/target/site/project-reports.html

Shows empty report "Allure "
Click on hyper link "Allure" it navigates to 
/allure-testng-example/target/site/allure-maven-plugin/index.html 
Shows "Loading page" which never loads.